# AlignIO cannot find records in FASTA file

Tags: python, biopython

I want to start using Biopython to align sequence files, but the library keeps giving me errors. My code is as follows:

```
from Bio import AlignIO
import Bio

alignment = AlignIO.read("A_prot.fasta","fasta")
print alignment
```

I made sure to put `A_prot.fasta` in the same directory as my program, but I receive an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bio_seq_align.py", line 5, in <module>
   alignment = AlignIO.read("A_prot.fasta","fasta")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/biopython-1.61-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/Bio/AlignIO/__init__.py", line 427, in read
raise ValueError("No records found in handle")
ValueError: No records found in handle
```

Comment: Have you checked the format of your fasta file?

Comment: what do your fasta file contains ? protein sequences ? or one alignment ?

Comment: It contains protein sequences

Comment: I've tested you code it works for me. `>>> from Bio import AlignIO`
`>>> alignment = AlignIO.read("result_cbpa.fasta","fasta")`
`>>> print alignment`
`SingleLetterAlphabet() alignment with 502 rows and 781 columns`

Comment: Can you post a sample of your fasta file which reproduces the problem?

Comment: you can find it here ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/ipd/imgt/hla/A_prot.fasta

Answer (score 0):

One reason you might get "ValueError: No records found in handle" is if the file on your machine was actually empty.

This is what happens for me using ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/ipd/imgt/hla/A_prot.fasta which you linked to in the comments above,

```
>>> from Bio import AlignIO
>>> align = AlignIO.read("A_prot.fasta", "fasta")
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: Sequences must all be the same length
```

This is the expected result - that FASTA file is not set of aligned sequences. If you want to load it as an alignment, first run an alignment tool like MUSCLE, Clustal Omega, etc. However, having looked at the file and the range of lengths, I doubt that is sensible for this example:

```
>>> from Bio import SeqIO
>>> lengths = set(len(record) for record in SeqIO.parse("A_prot.fasta", "fasta"))
>>> lengths
set([17, 19, 26, 50, 51, 53, 59, 65, 66, 71, 72, 73, 74, ..., 364, 365])
```

Answer (score 0):

peterjc makes a good point the `AlignIO` takes in aligned sequences which must be of the same length. If you want to read in a fata containig unaligned sequences you can use `SeqIO` as follows:

```
>>> from Bio import SeqIO
>>> handle = open("A_prot.fasta", "rU")
>>> print handle
<open file 'A_prot.fasta', mode 'rU' at 0x13fc1d8>
>>>
```

To read in the sequences into a dictionary you can use something like:

```
>>> record_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"))
>>> print len(record_dict)
2186 # Fasta file contains 2186 entries
>>>
```

To record ID becomes the key in this case. To access information associated with a particular key use:

```
>>> record_dict['HLA:HLA00001']
SeqRecord(seq=Seq('MAVMAPRTLLLLLSGALALTQTWAGSHSMRYFFTSVSRPGRGEPRFIAVGYVDD...CKV', SingleLetterAlphabet()), id='HLA:HLA00001', name='HLA:HLA00001', description='HLA:HLA00001 A*01:01:01:01 365 bp', dbxrefs=[])
>>>
```

Refer to the [AlignIO](http://biopython.org/wiki/AlignIO) and  [SeqIO](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) documentation for futher information

Comment: Your first example doesn't actually parse the FASTA file. And for the second example using a dictionary, the Bio.SeqIO.index function might be more sensible here given the number of entries.